# Need to filter list using max()

Tags: sql, ms-access

The thing is, I'm trying to create a table that displays only the max number of votes to a given candidate. For that, it was needed to combine three different tables (this ones are in spanish) `Sedes`, `Candidatos` and `Voto`.
I've got to the point where executing the followning lines, gives me the list with all the total number of votes per candidate per stablishment:

```
SELECT sedes.nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre AS Candidato, count(voto.numcandidato) AS TOTAL
From (Voto INNER JOIN Sedes ON Sedes.sede_id=Voto.sede_id) 
INNER JOIN Candidatos ON Voto.numcandidato=Candidatos.numcandidato
GROUP BY nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre
```

Now this is not my end product, what I need is for the list to only show me the candidate in each establishment that's got the maximum ammount of votes. I tried doing this:

```
SELECT sedes.nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre AS Candidato, count(voto.numcandidato) AS TOTAL
From (Voto INNER JOIN Sedes ON Sedes.sede_id=Voto.sede_id) 
INNER JOIN Candidatos ON Voto.numcandidato=Candidatos.numcandidato
GROUP BY nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre
HAVING max(TOTAL)
```

But when executing, access prompts me to give a value to `TOTAL` like when using a parameters clause. As you can see, I also ran into trouble when trying to use `Candidato` inside the `GROUP BY` and worked around it by copying the exact expression used in the `SELECT` clause. Maybe this has something to do with the other problem?

Many, many thanks for all the help!

Comment: Replace COUNT by MAX, ditch your (invalid) HAVING clause and see if gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider running an aggregate then a correlated subquery for a ranking variable of candidates under each establishment. Then, pick all records with `rank = 1`:

Helper Query *(save as a query object to be referenced below)*

```
SELECT s.nombresede, c.apellido & ', ' & c.nombre AS Candidato, 
       COUNT(voto.numcandidato) AS TOTAL
FROM (Voto v 
INNER JOIN Sedes s ON s.sede_id = v.sede_id) 
INNER JOIN Candidatos c ON c.numcandidato = v.numcandidato
GROUP BY s.nombresede, c.apellido & ', ' & c.nombre
```

Final Query

```
SELECT m.nombresede, m.Candidato, m.[rank]
FROM
   (SELECT q.nombresede, q.Candidato,
          (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM myHelperQuery sub
           WHERE sub.nombresede = q.nombresede
             AND sub.TOTAL >= q.TOTAL) AS [rank]
    FROM myHelperQuery q
   ) AS m
WHERE m.[rank] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TOTAL` is not defined. Its not possible to use an Alias this way. So the `Max()` is trying to evaluate but Access doesnt know what your `TOTAL` is, so it asks for an input. This one should do the trick:

```
SELECT sedes.nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre AS Candidato, count(voto.numcandidato) AS total, Max(voto.numcandidato) AS maximum
From (Voto INNER JOIN Sedes ON Sedes.sede_id=Voto.sede_id) 
INNER JOIN Candidatos ON Voto.numcandidato=Candidatos.numcandidato
GROUP BY nombresede, candidatos.apellido & ", " & candidatos.nombre
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering my question. I see what you mean, but in that case I would need to use a GROUP BY with max(voto.numcandidato) which is wrong. I might have been somewhat confusing when explaining, the thing is when using the very first code I posted Access gives me a complete list with the ammount of votes per candidate in each of the establishments. But I only wish for it to show me the name and votes for the one man who got the most of them...data is stored in the following way: nombresede = name of establishment, sede_id = number of establishment

Comment: candidatos.apellido and candidatos.nombre are the surname and name of the candidates respectively, and finally voto.numcandidato is the own personal id that belongs to each candidate. These are all stored in different tables, and used to correlate them with the INNER JOINs used. Hope I've been able to clarify my situation

Comment: Ah, ok in this case you can go with the answer from @Parfait.

Comment: Thank you for your dedication, I've managed to get it going with the help of both of you